# Assigning the Result of a BASH Command to a Variable

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to execute the following command inside of a BASH script and I've tried all of the reasonable permutations of $(), ${}, and `` that I can think of but I just haven't been able to get it to work.  I'd like to assign the result of this command to a variable:

`"scale=2; $var1/$var2" | bc`

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `echo` the commands into `bc`, like this:

```
var=$(echo "scale=2; $var1/$var2" | bc)
```

Or, as suggested in the comments (thanks!) and you're using BASH, you could use `<<<` instead:

```
var=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $var1/$var2")
```

While we're at it, you could also use a here document:

```
var=$(bc << EOF
scale=2; $var1/$var2
EOF
)
```

Here's a test showing that they all do the same thing:

```
var1=10
var2=2
out1=$(echo "scale=2; $var1/$var2" | bc)
out2=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $var1/$var2")
out3=$(bc << EOF
scale=2; $var1/$var2
EOF
)
echo "$out1 $out2 $out3"
```

output: `5.00 5.00 5.00`

Comment: This edited version works beautifully.  I didn't know I needed to "echo" the command within the $(...).  Thank you very much for taking the time to help.

Comment: You can dispense with the need for the `echo` by doing `var=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $var1/$var2")`. However, since `echo` is a builtin in bash, it might not actually buy you anything, other than a slightly shorter and perhaps somewhat cleaner looking line of code.

Comment: No problem. Also, I suggested the `<<<` approach because the OP specifically mentioned that this was a bash script, but it's good to keep in mind that `<<<` is a bashism and is therefore not portable.

Comment: @MikeHolt, `echo` is a builtin, but the pipe means a subshell. A portable alternative would be to use a here-doc instead

`var=$( bc << EOF
  scale=2; $var1/$var2
EOF
)`

 Those are 4 lines, can't put that in a comment ...

Comment: @Scrutinizer My point about `echo` being a builtin was that eliminating the `echo` wouldn't necessarily buy you any performance increase, whereas if `echo` was a separate executable, then `$(echo | ...)` costs you an extra process call. Also, eliminating the pipe doesn't *necessarily* result in a performance increase either, since it's possible (perhaps likely?) that bash implements `<<<` internally by using a pipe. I don't know for sure one way or another, but it wouldn't suprise me if `foo <<< bar` is just syntactic sugar for `echo bar | foo` and thus functionally identical, pipes and all.

Comment: @MikeHolt, I know, your remark about the builtin echo was a good remark, but I added that the pipe would mean an extra subshell. I just tested the three options and the echo-and-pipe method uses one more subshell than the other two methods..

Comment: @Scrutinizer Good to know. I like `<<<` because it's shorter and (to my eye) cleaner. It's nice to know it's also more efficient. As for portability, the scripts I write are mainly for my own personal use, and so portability concerns are pretty much nonexistent.

Comment: This has all been very informative discussion, thank you all very much.  I am fortunate enough that portability and performance don't matter in this very simple case, but I'm definitely happy to have learned all of this to use when I write scripts going forward.  Thanks again!